# Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED, Manifest Merger Failed with multiple errors in React Native using Android Sdk Version 31

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, firebase, react-native

Getting the error below when I try to run npm run android to launch a React Native app.  Have done npm install --legacy-peer-deps, done a clean git clone, and wiped all user data on the android emulator device.

I have also tried setting android:exported="false" in the AndroidManifest.xml file but get the same error. Android Sdk version 31. Using VSCode as the text editor.

```
PS C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app> npm run android 

> app@0.0.1 preandroid
> python ./preCompile/parse_game_data.py


> app@0.0.1 android
> gulp set --env=dev && react-native run-android

[18:45:27] Using gulpfile C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\gulpfile.js
[18:45:27] Starting 'set'...
[18:45:27] Starting 'del'...
[18:45:27] Finished 'del' after 19 ms
[18:45:27] Starting 'move'...
[18:45:27] Finished 'move' after 15 ms
[18:45:27] Finished 'set' after 37 ms
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1688 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 12 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_analytics
:react-native-firebase_analytics package.json found at C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\analytics\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_analytics:firebase.bom using default value: 29.1.0
:react-native-firebase_analytics package.json found at C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\analytics\package.json
:react-native-firebase_analytics:version set from package.json: 14.9.1 (14,9,1 - 14009001)
:react-native-firebase_analytics:android.compileSdk using custom value: 31
:react-native-firebase_analytics:android.targetSdk using custom value: 31
:react-native-firebase_analytics:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_analytics:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\react-native\android

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_app
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:firebase.bom using default value: 29.1.0
:react-native-firebase_app:play.play-services-auth using default value: 20.1.0
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:version set from package.json: 14.9.1 (14,9,1 - 14009001)
:react-native-firebase_app:android.compileSdk using custom value: 31
:react-native-firebase_app:android.targetSdk using custom value: 31
:react-native-firebase_app:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_app:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\react-native\android

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_auth
:react-native-firebase_auth package.json found at C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\auth\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_auth:firebase.bom using default value: 29.1.0
:react-native-firebase_auth package.json found at C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\auth\package.json
:react-native-firebase_auth:version set from package.json: 14.9.1 (14,9,1 - 14009001)
:react-native-firebase_auth:android.compileSdk using custom value: 31
:react-native-firebase_auth:android.targetSdk using custom value: 31
:react-native-firebase_auth:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_auth:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\react-native\android

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_database
:react-native-firebase_database package.json found at C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\database\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_database:firebase.bom using default value: 29.1.0
:react-native-firebase_database package.json found at C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\database\package.json
:react-native-firebase_database:version set from package.json: 14.9.1 (14,9,1 - 14009001)
:react-native-firebase_database:android.compileSdk using custom value: 31
:react-native-firebase_database:android.targetSdk using custom value: 31
:react-native-firebase_database:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_database:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\react-native\android

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_firestore
:react-native-firebase_firestore package.json found at C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\firestore\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_firestore:firebase.bom using default value: 29.1.0
:react-native-firebase_firestore package.json found at C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\firestore\package.json
:react-native-firebase_firestore:version set from package.json: 14.9.1 (14,9,1 - 14009001)
:react-native-firebase_firestore:android.compileSdk using custom value: 31
:react-native-firebase_firestore:android.targetSdk using custom value: 31
:react-native-firebase_firestore:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_firestore:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\react-native\android

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_functions
:react-native-firebase_functions package.json found at C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\functions\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_functions:firebase.bom using default value: 29.1.0
:react-native-firebase_functions package.json found at C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\functions\package.json
:react-native-firebase_functions:version set from package.json: 14.9.1 (14,9,1 - 14009001)
:react-native-firebase_functions:android.compileSdk using custom value: 31
:react-native-firebase_functions:android.targetSdk using custom value: 31
:react-native-firebase_functions:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_functions:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\react-native\android

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_storage
:react-native-firebase_storage package.json found at C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\storage\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_storage:firebase.bom using default value: 29.1.0
:react-native-firebase_storage package.json found at C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\storage\package.json
:react-native-firebase_storage:version set from package.json: 14.9.1 (14,9,1 - 14009001)
:react-native-firebase_storage:android.compileSdk using custom value: 31
:react-native-firebase_storage:android.targetSdk using custom value: 31
:react-native-firebase_storage:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_storage:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\react-native\android

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
AAR for react-native-reanimated has been found
C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\react-native-reanimated-68-hermes.aar

> Configure project :storyly-react-native
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
208 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 206 up-to-date
C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-33:20 Error:
        android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:34:9-40:20 Error:
        android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyFloatingActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-33:20 Error:
        android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:34:9-40:20 Error:
        android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyFloatingActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s

    at makeError (C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Velocity\Velocity-React-Native\app\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "19.2.0"

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            // For Android Users, we need to use NDK 23, otherwise the build will
            // fail due to paths longer than the OS limit
            ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3')
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.1.2")
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10"
        classpath "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.1.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: any update? facing the same problem from today while was working fine. Didn't find any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Look like it's happening by jitpack.io down, try adding this in `android/app/build.gradle`

```
implementation "androidx.test:core:1.4.0" (add to dependencies)
```